# Adding a background image to a card component from props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I tried to insert a background image into the card component from props, got no error but the image did not display in the card component either. I can't really tell what I'm doing wrong. Please I need a better idea/way to go about fixing this issue. Thanks

project.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardTitle, CardText, CardActions, Button } from "react-mdl";

const Project = ({ image, technology, description, projectName }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Card
        shadow={0}
        style={{ width: "320px", height: "320px", margin: "auto" }}
      >
        <CardTitle
          expand
          style={{
            color: "#fff",
            background: `url(${image})`,
          }}
        >
          {technology}
        </CardTitle>
        <h6>{projectName}</h6>
        <CardText>{description}</CardText>
        <CardActions border>
          <Button colored>View Updates</Button>
        </CardActions>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Project;
```

projects.js

```
import React from "react";
import { projectList } from "./projectList";
import Project from "./project";

const Projects = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {projectList.map((user, i) => {
        return (
          <Project
            key={i}
            id={projectList[i].id}
            technology={projectList[i].technology}
            projectName={projectList[i].projectName}
            description={projectList[i].description}
            image={projectList[i].image}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Projects;
```

The image is imported into the projectList.js array of objects

projectList.js

```
import MIT from "../img/mit.png";

export const projectList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    technology: "HTML | CSS | Bootstrap",
    projectName: "Lorem",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
    image: { MIT },
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    technology: "Reactjs",
    projectName: "Lorem",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
    image: { MIT },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    technology: "React Native",
    projectName: "Lorem",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
    image: { MIT },
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    technology: "Vue",
    projectName: "Lorem",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
    image: { MIT },
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    technology: "Angular",
    projectName: "Lorem",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
    image: { MIT },
  },

];
```

Comment: Do you have an example of this running anywhere?

Comment: No... not really @go_diego

I have edited it though to show projectList.js, where the image url is linked from

Comment: If you check the value of `image`, is it what you expect it to be?

Comment: Like this?... No. 
Putting the image link as the value to the key "image" in the object at projectList.js?... Yes.
But it's not showing still

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is from projectList.js, the image key in the objects of the array.

Should have been like this

```
import MIT from "../img/mit.png";

export const projectList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    technology: "HTML | CSS | Bootstrap",
    projectName: "Lorem",
    description: "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.",
    image: `${MIT}`,
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The example shows setting a `Card` background like this:

```
<Card shadow={0} style={{width: '320px', height: '320px', margin: 'auto'}}>
    <CardTitle expand style={{color: '#fff', background: 'url(http://www.getmdl.io/assets/demos/dog.png) bottom right 15% no-repeat #46B6AC'}}>Update</CardTitle>
    <CardText>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Aenan convallis.
    </CardText>
    <CardActions border>
        <Button colored>View Updates</Button>
    </CardActions>
</Card>
```

Try using inline CSS to set a `height` and `width` or background property such as `cover`. Maybe the image is there but it doesn't have a height or width and isn't displaying.

Also, have you tried just putting the image in a `img` tag to test that it works in your component? Most likely the image isn't imported correctly or it is and it isn't showing because it lacks height and width.

Try something like this:

```
background: 'url(http://www.getmdl.io/assets/demos/welcome_card.jpg) center / cover'
```

Comment: I did put the image in an img tag like you suggested and it did not display the image, so I'm guessing the problem is from how it is imported. So i guess my question now should be "How do i import the image correct into the projectList.js page where i exported an array of objects"?